# How to get minified files in project ( Gatsby / React )

Tags: reactjs, minify, azure-application-insights, gatsby

gatsby version = 2.0.0-beta.19

node version = v10.6.0

npm version = 6.1.0

VScode version = 1.25.1

When adding minified files (.min.js or .js with minified content) to my react Gatsby project, I get the following error when I try to do `gatsby develop`:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                      10:41:47 AM
 error  in ./src/components/appinsights.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/mnt/d/my_site/src/components/appinsights.js
  2:185  error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  2:248  warning  Unexpected use of comma operator                                       no-sequences
  2:493  warning  Unexpected use of comma operator                                       no-sequences
  2:649  error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  2:660  warning  Unexpected use of comma operator                                       no-sequences
  2:761  warning  Unexpected use of comma operator                                       no-sequences
  7:1    error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  7:31   warning  Unexpected use of comma operator                                       no-sequences

✖ 8 problems (3 errors, 5 warnings)
```

I added a new file "./src/components/appinsights.js" and the contents of the file are from inside the script tag of [App insights JS snippet](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)

```
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(a){
    function b(a){c[a]=function(){var b=arguments;c.queue.push(function(){c[a].apply(c,b)})}}var c={config:a},d=document,e=window;setTimeout(function(){var b=d.createElement("script");b.src=a.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(b)});try{c.cookie=d.cookie}catch(a){}c.queue=[];for(var f=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];f.length;)b("track"+f.pop());if(b("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("startTrackEvent"),b("stopTrackEvent"),b("startTrackPage"),b("stopTrackPage"),b("flush"),!a.disableExceptionTracking){f="onerror",b("_"+f);var g=e[f];e[f]=function(a,b,d,e,h){var i=g&&g(a,b,d,e,h);return!0!==i&&c["_"+f](a,b,d,e,h),i}}return c
}({
    instrumentationKey: "<my_key>"
});

window.appInsights=appInsights,appInsights.queue&&0===appInsights.queue.length&&appInsights.trackPageView();
```

In my "./src/components/layout.js"

```
import appinsightsFile from './appinsights.js'
...
<Helmet
    title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}>
    <html lang="en" />
    <script type="application/ld+json">{appinsightsFile}</script>
</Helmet>
...
```

I am not sure if this is a react issue or Gatsby. I can't seem to get any minified code to work with my application.

I have tried:

- inline app insights code in my layout.js
- taking the script tags out of the helmet code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that experienced and wanted to comment on this, but I need 50 reputation. Anyways, maybe we can solve your issue together.

First off, why do you use type `application/ld+json` instead of `text/javascript` as stated in the *ApplicationInsights-JS* readme?

To debug this issue try to insert the contents of `appinsights.js` directly into the script tag.

The following should work:

```
<Helmet
    title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}>
    <html lang="en" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {`SCRIPT`}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

If not, try [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/#adding-custom-javascript) instead.

Note the back ticks inside `{}`. If this is working correctly, proceed with your component.

[As I know](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-images-fonts-files/) – correct me if I go wrong – the use case of directly importing a file in Gatsby belongs to static files. You could simply `import logo from './Logo.svg'` and this will return the url to that file. Behind the scenes, Webpack will include that file in the bundle and you can reference it like in `src` and `href` attributes.

If you want to include that JavaScript string from a component (that what you placed inside the `components` directory is not a component), you should write a component for that, which renders this JavaScript.

I didn't try that myself, but I think this could work with some modification.

The errors you are facing are part of `eslint`, I think. The compiler (Webpack?) expects non-minified ES6 JavaScript. Again, correct me if I am wrong.

Some sort of a stateless functional component should help you here:

appinsights.js

```
import React from 'react'

const AppInsights = () => {
  return `
    SCRIPT
  `
}

export default AppInsights
```

layout.js

```
import AppInsights from './appinsights.js' // Replace with your path.

<Helmet
    title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}>
    <html lang="en" />
    <script type="text/javascript"><AppInsights /></script>
</Helmet>
```

But I think it is safer to work with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as before.

Comment: The backticks were what I was missing. I wasn't expecting the JS needed to be treated as a template literal. Though, I'm still not thrilled with the solution and would like to include raw minified JS instead.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-images-fonts-files/

> If you put a file into the static folder, it will not be processed by Webpack. Instead it will be copied into the public folder untouched.

You create a folder as `your_gatsby_project_folder/static` (not in `project/src`), and put your `minified files` from outside in it.  Whatever is in the static will be copied onto public folder so you can link to them as usual

```js
// in your react file, you can use script tag to link to the minified files

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <script src="/path/to/your/min.js" />

      whatever
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a minified javascript file and add it to a `<script` tag in the `<head` of your Gatsby site, you do not want to `import` it.

Check the [docs on custom html](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/).

You could put the file into the `static/` folder, then it will be copied into your built output. Then `cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js` and edit `src/html.js` to add the `<script` tag you want.

However, this is not a very good approach. You would be better to give Gatsby the unminified file if you can. Then you can import it in the normal Gatsby way, and Gatsby will handle minifying it. Gatsby is really good at figuring out what javascript is required where. It's part of why Gatsby sites are so insanely fast. You will lose some of that advantage if you use the approach above.